# How would you include a specific module to load at boot in Debian?

Tags: debian, python, systemd, modprobe

I am working with Klipper for 3D printing, and I came across a pull request that allowed for TTY support in Klipper, to allow a Mosaic Palete 3 Pro to control the printer for its Connected Mode.
I have merged the file that needed to be changed (klippy.py) to open up TTY. However, when I reached out to the author of the change, they said, "I just made sure the gadget serial driver (g_serial) is loaded on my RPi and that M105 probes from P3P appear on /dev/ttyGS0."

This leads me to my issue. I need the gadget serial driver available at boot, prior to the klipper service launch.

1. Modified the ExecStart in klipper.service to attempt a modprobe on g_serial before booting klippy, and passing it /dev/ttyGS0,
   I got errors for syntax regarding the python program.

```
[Unit]
Description=Klipper 3D Printer Firmware SV1
Documentation=https://www.klipper3d.org/
After=network-online.target
Wants=udev.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=biqu
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/biqu/klipper
EnvironmentFile=/home/biqu/printer_data/systemd/klipper.env
ExecStart=modprobe g_serial && /home/biqu/klippy-env/bin/python $KLIPPER_ARGS
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
```

2. Also tried to create another service, that `Requires=modprobe.target` and was required by the klipper service, same issue.
3. My third and final attempt so far, has been to create an entry in modprobe.d, however I was unsure of what the .conf should have been named and the contents of that file, for modprobe g_serial opening ttyGS0.

If things had gone well, I would have expected to automate the boot procedure for Klipper to detect and open the connection to TTY prior to running klippy.py

Answer (score 1):

In order to load a kernel module on boot, you just have to name that module in your `/etc/modules` file.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to write another service file that was required by klipper.service:

klippy_init.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Klipper 3D Printer Firmware SV1
Documentation=https://www.klipper3d.org/
Wants=modprobe

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=modprobe g_serial
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
```

and Klipper.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Klipper 3D Printer Firmware SV1
Documentation=https://www.klipper3d.org/
After=network-online.target
Wants=udev.target
Requires=klippy_init.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=biqu
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/biqu/klipper
EnvironmentFile=/home/biqu/printer_data/systemd/klipper.env
ExecStart=/home/biqu/klippy-env/bin/python $KLIPPER_ARGS
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
```